# How to mock WebdriverIO.Element with sinon-chai

Tags: sinon, webdriver-io, sinon-chai, wdio

I'm creating a web testing framework wrapping `wdio.js`.

In my framework, I need to translate from my wrapper object to `WebdriverIO.Element` so that I can call `getAttribute()` which hangs off of `$`. But I can't figure out how to spy/stub/mock `$` or `WebdriverIO.Element` such that I can find out what parameter `getAtribute()` was called with.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the answer may be to use `ts-sinon` which handles mocking `interface`s which is what `WebdriverIO.Element` appears to be. Will test and report back.